# Recursive tags hierarchy retrieval in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

(*Assumption: each tag may have a parent tag, i.e. there exist a hierarchy of tags, without limiting its depth.*)

Is there a way (possibly with just one query) to retrieve all the children tags of a tag with just SQL, i.e. without using a code?

**The problem is:**
I have a hierarchy of tags:

```
root-tag
- tag-child -> parent is tag-child
-- tag-child-depth-2 -> parent is tag-child-depth-2
--- tag-child-depth-3 -> parent is root-tag
- tag-other-child -> parent is root-tag
```

This could be represented in DB this way:

```
id | tag_name  | parent_tag_id
-------------------------------------------------
1  | root-tag  | (NULL)
2  | tag-child | 1
```

I have been only given the top tag ("root-tag"). How to rerieve *all* the child tags?

**Expected result**:
All the children tags (except root parent tag).
i.e.:

```
- tag-child
-- tag-child-depth-2
--- tag-child-depth-3
- tag-other-child
```

The actual way of represeting the result data is not that important (i.e. this could be a simple list / array), however the most valuable would be a recursive array, maintaining the hierarchy - it's not obligatory though of course.

Comment: Please show us sample data, expected results, and you current attempt.

Comment: There are lot of way but where is your problem?

Comment: You showed sample data (though it is more helpful to know your actual column and table names) but not your expected results; there are a number of different ways you might want the data returned

Comment: @ysth ok. do you need more info?

Comment: Yes.  What do you want in each result row? Just id and name for each tag reachable from the root?  Or something else?  The database isn't going to return blnested arrays; if you want that, you'll need to figure out what it should return to make it easy to convert to nested arrays in your code

Comment: To do this without limits or without storing extra info for each tag requires MySQL 8 or mariadb 10.2

Comment: Ids and names of tags would be sufficient. The idea is to pursue the database as little as possible, i.e. with as little queries as possible. If hierarchy of tags is quite deep (like having 10 depth levels), I would need 10 queries to do this in a "standard" way...